# finding amount of errors that can be fixed based on code length

Tags: coding-theory, error-correcting-codes, hamming-code, hamming-distance

i tried to look online and search this site and others but haven't found any good explanation to the following simple question: how many errors can a code with length k(k>2)fix?

Comment: The answer depends on the code.

Comment: I conjecture that you have a more concrete question in mind. If so, I suggest asking it directly.